# IsPressed trigger doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, triggers

The style is in the Resources:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCornerSmart" TargetType="{x:Type vk:SmartButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type vk:SmartButton}">
                            <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#006AB6" BorderThickness="1" Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" >
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            LightGray
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>

                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding KeyCommand}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="52"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="52"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
            </Style>
```

I have a class named SmartButton which extends the Button class.

```
<vk:SmartButton Content="Some content" Grid.Column="3" Style="{DynamicResource RoundCornerSmart}" />
```

For this button, the background remains the same (white) when I press it, and i need it to be LightGrey. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Style RoundCorner is set to Type {x:Type Button}. Now if you want apply it to another object, like vk:SmartButton you need to create new style, appropiate for that type.

```
TargetType={x:Type vk:SmartButton}
```

Comment: But the smartbutton takes everything from the style: font, foreground, the rounded corners, just not the background when it's pressed. If the type isn't appropriate, why does it work for all of the other properties?

Comment: Apparently setting Style for type Button works as long as you don't override default template. Then wrong type makes it impossible to work as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You should have received a `XamlParseException` that said something along the lines of:

> 'Set property '`System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style`' threw an exception.' Line number '154' and line position '44'.

If you looked at the detail of that `Exception` and viewed the inner `Exception`, you would have seen something like this:

> '`Button`' `TargetType` does not match type of element '`SmartButton`'.

The reason for this is quite clear... you cannot apply a `Style` for one type to an instance of another type *especially* when you intend on providing a new `ControlTemplate` for it. In order to use your `Style` on your custom `Button`, you'll need to duplicate it and set the `Style.TargetType` property to:

```
<Style x:Key="SmartRoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type YourPrefix:SmartButton}">
    ...
</Style>
```

It's also worth pointing out that you probably don't need to extend the `Button` class at all as WPF provides many other ways to customise the standard `Button`.

Comment: But the smartbutton takes everything from the style: font, foreground, the rounded corners, just not the background when it's pressed. If the type isn't appropriate, why does it work for all of the other properties?

Comment: You asked a question and I answered it and then you changed it so that these answers don't make sense anymore... that's *not* how this website works. For all I know, if I answered your next question and you didn't like *that* answer, then you'd probably just change it again, so I'm 'out' at this point. Poor show.

Comment: I changed it according to your answer and it still doesn't work. You said i need to change the target type from Button to SmartButton. that's what I did and it still doesn't work. I'm sorry if you got offended, that really wasn't my intention.

Comment: I'm not offended at all, but you don't seem to understand what you have done. In future, please add an extra edit to your questions, instead of changing them. Any users seeing this question will wonder why these answers don't relate to this question now... you have broken the continuity of this question. As for *it still doesn't work*... your original question was titled *IsPressed works for one button but not for another* and you said *What am I doing wrong?*... *that* question was answered by two users. If you had a follow up question, then you should have asked a new question.

Comment: Ok, from now on I'll do that. It's too late for this question though. So, that question was answered by two users, but those two answers don't work.

Comment: *those two answers don't work*... you see, *that's* your problem. They *did* work. Both answers told you why only one `Style` would work and how to get both to work, which is *actually* what you asked. It's not our fault if you didn't ask the question that you wanted to in the first place. It's not our fault if those two *correct* answers didn't solve your whole problem... they just answered the question that you asked.